# Open a text file in the default text editor... via Java?

Tags: java, download, text-files

OK. Simple question. Maybe not so simple answer, though:

I have a file I downloaded in Java, and I know that it's a text file. Is there any way that I can use Java to open that text file in whatever the default text editor is? It has to work for all OS's, otherwise I would just make it open with Notepad.

:\ I guess that if there's no way to do this I could use JOptionPane and show the contents of the text file...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
```

[This links to the tutorial article on java.awt.Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html):

> Java™ Standard Edition version 6
> narrows the gap between performance
> and integration of native applications
> and Java applications. Along with the
> new system tray functionality, splash
> screen support, and enhanced printing
> for JTables , Java SE version 6
> provides the Desktop API
> (java.awt.Desktop) API, which allows
> Java applications to interact with
> default applications associated with
> specific file types on the host
> platform.

It is cross-platform, but may not be supported everywhere. There is a method you can call to check whether the Desktop API is available, called isDesktopSupported (see the link for more explanation). I was using this API the other day to open PDFs in a Swing client.

Unfortunately there is a [known bug affecting some Windows platforms (XP and 2003)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6631015) that will crash the JVM. *Write once, debug everywhere*, as usual. Anyway, for Windows there is a [nice workaround](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip66.html) which still uses the user's preferred application:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
  String cmd = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + file.getCanonicalPath();
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} 
else {
  Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
}
```

Comment: OK Cool-- that's cross-platform and handles everything? :)

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of Desktop -- my Java pretty much stops with 5.

Comment: Don't forget there is also `Desktop.open(File)` (sometimes opens read-only) & `Desktop.print(File)` for slightly different actions.

Comment: That bug report states.. *"Only with Windows 2003 , **works fine with winXP.**"*  (emphasis mine) If Win. 2003 is all it crashes on, I won't be losing sleep over it.  Specify XP as the minimum and lose a few clients - no stress.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, it says that. But my boss' boss was running my program, *on XP*, and it crashed for him. So I was stressed.

Comment: Only problem here: When you have http://someserver/somedir/myReport.doc then http takes priority over .doc and instead of Word/OpenOffice the browser opens. This is a Windows limitation.

Comment: @stwissel: would it help to map a drive letter on the client to the webdav server, then use the drive letter instead of http?

Comment: does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 - but Desktop.open(File) does, thanks to @AndrewThompson

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().edit( ) / open( ) work only if a default editor is already associated with that extension. Else it crashes (i ran it on win 10) saying that "No application is associated with the specified file..."

Isn't there a way to just open the default text editor (whatever) of the current OS?

Answer (score 6):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you could configure in the text editor and use Runtime.exec to start it.  But I can't think of any way to determine the default editor, especially in a system-independent fashion.

Maybe your best option is to identify which of the several most popular platforms you're on and then find a way to start the default editor on that platform.  Eg, on Window you'll get the default editor if you do "start filename.txt", and I'm pretty sure there's a Linux equivalent.