# Waiting for external application to close

Tags: java

Using instructions in [Open a text file in the default text editor… via Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273221/open-a-text-file-in-the-default-text-editor-via-java), I am opening an external file editor to edit a file like this;

```
    try {
        File temp = File.createTempFile("commit-", ".tmp");
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
            String cmd = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + temp.getCanonicalPath();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Reached this line");
        } else {
            Desktop.getDesktop().edit(temp);
        }
    } catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I don't want my program to continue executing until that editor exits. My solution was to use `waitfor()`, however, I am seeing the message `Reached this line` while external application -- "notepad++"  in this case -- still running. I am running windows 7, netbeans 7.3.1 and jdk 1.7.

Also, I have no idea how to do it in else block.